# React native (expo go) не видит инструменты разработчика

Tags: reactjs, отладка, react-native, инструменты-разработчика

нужна ваша помощь не могу разобраться почему когда запускаю сборку( expo go ) и жму Press j │ open debugger консоль через симулятор ios то консоль разработчика пустая только в источниках есть ip проекта с папками с которыми нечего сделать нельзя , пробовал обновлять expogo , sdk , и когда пробую на реальном девайсе тоже самое нечего не работает даже варианты ИИ не помогли решить проблему . Спасибо